# Comparing dates java.util.date with Date datatype in db

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have java.util.date and there is a column date in Oracle db table of  DATE datatype and value is stored in format 31-JAN-36. I want to compare java.util.date with the date column in db and return if both matches. I tried no of ways using to_char, to_date functions but it's not working, can any help please help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share your implementation of the problem, so we can see where you block.

Comment: AND p.starts_On= TO_CHAR(to_date('Wed Oct 01 00:00:00 EDT 2014' ,'dd-mon-yy') ;

Comment: I am getting date as java.util.date so this is the string implementation of it as 'Wed Oct 01 00:00:00 EDT 2014', and this starts_on column has value as 30-SEP-35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the SimpleDateFormat:

```
Date date = ..your date..
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YY");
String where = "p.starts_on = '" + sdf.format(date) + "'";
```

Comment: I was knowing this and doing it somewhere else, but the time I was reading your comment I realized to do it in query too, and it ran successfully, so thanks.